# Rogue Extension posting unauthorized stuff to peoples blogs

Tags: extensions

How can I find out what extension actually posted a big spammy advertisement to blog/cat/news on our site?  More specifically where the parasite code may be?

It looks they they've done this to TONS of other people as well.

https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3Ablog%2Fcat%2Fnews%20aheadworks&rct=j

I'm all for a "powered by" or similar branding...but seriously...our customers don't care what kind of magento extensions we're using.  This is very blatantly just done for SEO purposes...and I'm certain that site owners have no clue it's happening.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an Aheadworks extension for maybe a blog module and it posts a first demo blog article when the module is setup?

Maybe this one: http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/free-stuff/blog.html ?

If so, then this is no spam, but just an illustration, you can delete that article easily.

Comment: Agreed. You should QA code and extensions before deploying it to your website. This is nothing more than the default post to demo what is possible with the blog module.

Comment: Looks like it came with the theme we used.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Still feel a bit slighted that they used that many potent-anchor-text links in their "example page".  I suppose banking on people not using your extension to promote your extension works though with the number of results.

Comment: @Jimmy Agreed, this is pretty "clever" ;)